# getTotalLength on line element (svg) in Internet Explorer /Edge

Tags: javascript, html

`getTotalLength` method does not work in Internet Explorer or Edge. It gives the following error

> Object doesn't support property or method 'getTotalLength'

Same will work properly in Firefox/Chrome. With these browsers, it gives the total length of line as expected.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength) does not say about internet explorer support for `getTotalLength` (a question mark is given)

Could any one help me to figure out what is the best alternative.

What I could think is, check for browser  support for `getTotalLength` and if browser does not supporti, find the length of line using mathematical formula, or change line to path because `getTotalLength` seems to be supported on path element.

Comment: Check [can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=getTotalLength)

Answer (score 1):

You can check browser compatibility from [Can i use](https://caniuse.com/#search=getTotalLength)

You can easily do that by using plain javascript

```js
// get line element by using any getElement method
var line = document.getElementById("line-1");

//calculate distance between edge points by using following formula 
var len = dist(line.x1.baseVal.value, line.x2.baseVal.value,
               line.y1.baseVal.value, line.y2.baseVal.value);

function dist(x1, x2, y1, y2){
    return Math.sqrt( (x2-=x1)*x2 + (y2-=y1)*y2 );
}
```